# Title for trimesh visualizations

Tags: visualization, trimesh

How can I add a title to `trimesh` visualizations? For example, I want to do `mesh.show()` and have a window pop up with a custom title at the top to differentiate different visualizations. Just using `mesh.show()` results in the title being the python script name.